# Menu bar XML searching app?

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation, xml

I'm thinking a simple search app that can be reached from the menu bar and I have put my XML-files in the settings and then I can search through it to find whatever the XML-file is storing. For example would provide an XML file of products (reference file structured with keys for price, name, etc…) and I quickly wanna know what price a product is then I can search for that product and having all info about it displayed there.

I wonder if there exist any XML search app x preferably one with a menu bar UI for macOS?

Comment: That really is a very narrow spec for a search app. The number of people needing it would probably mean the chances of anyone having made it are very slim. Spotlight can search file contents.